# Exponential map for matrix Lie groups and smallness of the argument

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-exponential

From the [Wikipedia page of the Adjoint Representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Definition) we can read

> If $G$ is an immersed Lie subgroup of the general linear group
> $\mathrm {GL} _{n}(\mathbb {C} )$ (called immersely linear Lie group), then the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak {g}}$ consists of matrices and the exponential map is the matrix exponential $\operatorname {exp} (X)=e^{X}$ for matrices $X$ with small operator norms. We will compute the derivative of $\Psi _{g}$ at $e$. For $g$ in $G$ and small $X$ in ${\mathfrak {g}}$, the curve ${\displaystyle t\to \exp(tX)}$ has derivative $X$ at $t = 0$, one then gets:
> $${\displaystyle \operatorname {Ad} _{g}(X)=(d\Psi _{g})_{e}(X)=(\psi _{g}\circ \exp(tX))'(0)=(g\exp(tX)g^{-1})'(0)=gXg^{-1}}$$
> where on the right we have the products of matrices. If ${\displaystyle G\subset \mathrm {GL} _{n}(\mathbb {C} )}$ is a closed subgroup (that is, $G$ is a matrix Lie group), then this formula is valid for all g in G and all $X$ in ${\mathfrak {g}}$.

My question is: **Why is it necessary for $X$ to be an *small* element in ${\mathfrak {g}}$?**

I don't see this being used at any point of the proof, and I believe that the exponential map should be well defined for matrices as the usual Taylor series.

Is the smallness of the group element necessary to ensure differentiability at the origin? I don't se why, as we're *differentiating with respect to $t$*, and not to $X$.

**Many thanks!**

Comment: No need for $X$ to be small here, you are right.

Comment: The only reason to assume $X$ small is to ensure that the matrix exponential converges but I don't believe that is necessary here and it should always converge. (It only starts to matter if you want you use the BCH formula or define a local inverse to the exponential)

Comment: Cool, many thanks!